# How to solve table counter in Web Crawler (Selenium and Webdriver)

Tags: python, selenium, html-table, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I have some questions about a web crawler. I need to crawl hkgolden website.

[image]

[image]

I used Selenium and Webdriver (Chromedriver) to finish this web crawler.

Now, I want to count the number of the following table:

`https://forumd.hkgolden.com/topics.aspx?type=BW&page=1`

I used Selenium and Webdriver (Chromedriver) to finish this web crawler.

[image]

[image]

Therefore, I need to write some code is about counter. I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5pCd6-ZvQ0) about web crawling a table:

I know their method can solve the problem and they used len() to count it, but I used to my website and my code. I cannot count successfully. I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File ".\hkgolden.py", line 42, in <module>
    cols = len(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td")) #count number of columns
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

Now, I only can write an absolute value to finish this crawler. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For list you can use `.find_elements` not `.find_element`, so you can get the size.

```
cols = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td")) #count number of columns
```